# Community wiki revision and user links separation

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, ownership

For wiki posts (e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/339911)) link to the user with the most contribution placed on the next line to the percent value:

[image: revs-users]

Should this `26%` be on the same line with the user link? It might look like this:

[image: revs-users-proposal]

As I see in Transifex this could be easily fixed by modifing string:

> $RevisionCount$ revs, $AuthorCount$ users $TopUserPercentage$%$br$$TopUserName$

If moving percent string to the next line is unwanted, could a comma be added after `users`?

Comment: The reason it's the way it is is likely to avoid confusion with the different link targets, so the comma is probably the best.

Comment: @NathanTuggy another way is to include % into the link to the user profile.